# Not supported platforms for java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop()

Tags: java, cross-platform, desktop

Since Java 6 there is a class `java.awt.Desktop`. There are some nice methods but the class is not supported on all platforms. The methods [`java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#getDesktop()) throws an

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Desktop API is not supported
>   on the current platform

on some platforms. Or the method [`java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#isDesktopSupported()) return false.

I know that it work on Windows XP, Windows 2003 and also Windows Vista. The question is on which platform is it not supported?

Answer (score 9):

Quote:

> Desktop API was developed to support
> Windows and Gnome only

from https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6486393

This [article](http://java-hamster.blogspot.com/2007/06/troubles-with-javaawtdesktop-browse.html) however says that even Gnome support is flawed on Fedora.

Comment: Are you aware if there are plans to port this functionality to other OS ?

Answer (score 3):

Works on OS X, too.

Comment: Doesnt work with Mac / OS X. Which version have you checked it with ?

Answer (score 3):

Does not work in the current Debian (squeeze) whether in gnome or fvwm.
I did not try kde.

This bug prevents the latest version of limewire to start. The stack output is:

FATAL ERROR!

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.limegroup.gnutella.gui.Initializer$6.run(Unknown Source)

.......

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The system tray is not supported on the current platform.
    at java.awt.SystemTray.getSystemTray(SystemTray.java:151)

Comment: I'm having trouble with Ubuntu 11.10 & Gnome Classic / Gnome3 too, using both openjdk-6 & openjdk-7..

Answer (score 2):

Well its not Supported into the Ubuntu 12.04 and its giving Error like this.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The system tray is not supported on the current platform.
```

Answer (score 2):

to solve it on ubuntu, run the next command:

```
apt-get install libgnome2-0
```

Answer (score -1):

On arch linux, I had to install the AUR libgnome package

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately.