# Java: Open default mail application and create new mail and populate To and Subject fields

Tags: java, email, uri, default, mailto

Just wondering if anyone can help me with a problem I've come across in Java.

Is there functionality within Java to produce a section of code that will open the default email application on a user's PC? (I guess almost like a fancy mailto link...)

If there is - is it possible to populate fields such as the To and Subject fields?

Thanks,
Mike.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Desktop.mail(URI mailtoURI) is your friend!

Javadoc:

> Launches the mail composing window of the user default mail client, filling the message fields specified by a mailto: URI.
>
> A mailto: URI can specify message fields including "to", "cc", "subject", "body", etc. See [The mailto URL scheme (RFC 2368)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt) for the mailto: URI specification details.

Example Code:

```
Desktop desktop;
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() 
    && (desktop = Desktop.getDesktop()).isSupported(Desktop.Action.MAIL)) {
  URI mailto = new URI("mailto:john@example.com?subject=Hello%20World");
  desktop.mail(mailto);
} else {
  // TODO fallback to some Runtime.exec(..) voodoo?
  throw new RuntimeException("desktop doesn't support mailto; mail is dead anyway ;)");
}
```

Comment: Does this work all the time? I've tried to use awt.Desktop.getDesktop() before and soemtimes it just doesn't work - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102325/not-supported-platforms-for-java-awt-desktop-getdesktop

Comment: Thanks for your help sfussenegger! You made what sounded a difficult problem (for me) sound trivial. Cheers.

:)

Comment: @Bedwyr I think the question you've linked says it all. I've updated the code to reflect this. It should work reliably for Windows though; All users of different OSs are certainly able to write a mail themselves ;)

Comment: @BalusC it's always good to have some other talents if coding doesn't suffice ;)

Comment: Luckily, there are voodoo practicers here where I live ;)

Comment: note to myself: "no downvotes for @BalusC - might know voodoo practicers"

Comment: Not working for Ubuntu 17 with Gnome 3.24 and Java 8

Comment: On Windows, if there is no default mail program installed, a system dialog warning about that may show up below the Java application window and it may look like the application is not responding