# meeting can not be found in the calendar of organizer

Tags: java, email, calendar, ical4j

I am trying to send outlook meeting invite (outlook version 2013) using ical4j 1.0.4 and javax mail 1.5.0 libraries.

I followed this article - [How to send an iCal meeting request using Java Mail, and receive the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121715/how-to-send-an-ical-meeting-request-using-java-mail-and-receive-the-response) and i was able to send outlook meeting invite.

But organizer is not receiving the calendar invite.
If i send meeting invite from my email id to myself, i receive the event but it says "meeting can not be found in the calendar".

All Attendees receive the event and they can accept/decline and also see entry in their calendar.

Is there any way to get meeting added to organizer's calendar ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a meeting in the organizer calendar I'd suggest automating Outlook from your Java-based application. You may consider using the Ole automation technology for automating Outlook, for example:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleAutomation;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleFrame;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.Variant;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class OutlookMail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sendEMail();
    }

    public static void sendEMail() {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);

        // This should start outlook if it is not running yet
//      OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "OVCtl.OVCtl");
//      site.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);

        // Now get the outlook application
        OleClientSite site2 = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Outlook.Application");
        OleAutomation outlook = new OleAutomation(site2);

        OleAutomation mail = invoke(outlook, "CreateItem", 0 /* Mail item */).getAutomation();

        setProperty(mail, "BodyFormat", 2 /* HTML */);
        setProperty(mail, "Subject", "My test subject");
//      setProperty(mail, "From", "my@sender.org");
        setProperty(mail, "To", "<John Doe> my@recipient.org");
        setProperty(mail, "HtmlBody", "<html><body>This is an <b>HTML</b> test body.</body></html>");

//      if (null != attachmentPaths) {
//          for (String attachmentPath : attachmentPaths) {
//              File file = new File(attachmentPath);
//              if (file.exists()) {
//                  OleAutomation attachments = getProperty(mail, "Attachments");
//                  invoke(attachments, "Add", attachmentPath);
//              }
//          }
//      }

        invoke(mail, "Display" /* or "Send" */);

    }

    private static OleAutomation getProperty(OleAutomation auto, String name) {
        Variant varResult = auto.getProperty(property(auto, name));
        if (varResult != null && varResult.getType() != OLE.VT_EMPTY) {
            OleAutomation result = varResult.getAutomation();
            varResult.dispose();
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Variant invoke(OleAutomation auto, String command,
            String value) {
        return auto.invoke(property(auto, command),
                new Variant[] { new Variant(value) });
    }

    private static Variant invoke(OleAutomation auto, String command) {
        return auto.invoke(property(auto, command));
    }

    private static Variant invoke(OleAutomation auto, String command, int value) {
        return auto.invoke(property(auto, command),
                new Variant[] { new Variant(value) });
    }

    private static boolean setProperty(OleAutomation auto, String name,
            String value) {
        return auto.setProperty(property(auto, name), new Variant(value));
    }

    private static boolean setProperty(OleAutomation auto, String name,
            int value) {
        return auto.setProperty(property(auto, name), new Variant(value));
    }

    private static int property(OleAutomation auto, String name) {
        return auto.getIDsOfNames(new String[] { name })[0];
    }
}
```

See [How to create an E-Mail in Outlook and make it visible for the User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057759/how-to-create-an-e-mail-in-outlook-and-make-it-visible-for-the-user) for more information.

The sequence of property and method calls from the Outlook object model you can find in the following articles:

- [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/)
- [How To: Create a new recurring Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/07/outlook-recurring-appointment/)