# Java Desktop.open() never finish

Tags: java

Here is a code example that will never finish. All I do is open a file with Desktop.open(file). Program closes after I close opened file (for example text editor that pops up, or excel file).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("TextFile1.log");
    if (file.exists()) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                System.out.println("opening using desktop protocol " + desktop.toString());
                try {
//                  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gedit "+file);//this line of code works fine, but it is linux related
                    desktop.browse(file.toURI());//
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("File opened " + file.getName());
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    } else {
        System.out.println("File does not exists!");
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);//just so we do not exit before file is actually opened
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("End of program.");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Output that I get:

```
opening using desktop protocol java.awt.Desktop@7a8afb69
File opened TextFile1.log
End of program.
```

After some time, I decide to close opened file and I get below line in output as well:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I open file without blocking exit and that cross platform is supported?

I noticed this on Windows as well. All on Java 8.

Comment: When you say blocking exit, you mean blocking the Jvm from exiting?

Comment: Yes, JVM exit only when I close opened file. I will add this to output...

Comment: Cross platform support might be limited anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102325/not-supported-platforms-for-java-awt-desktop-getdesktop

Comment: Yeah I know about this question. Looks like I will have to implement different approach. This one was really promising and I used it for years, but lately it became issue with the growing number of users. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour when calling desktop.open(file) in place of desktop.browse(url)?

Comment: Yes, both methods lead to this method invoaction: sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer#gnome_url_show. Since this is native method I do not have control over it.

Comment: Seems to happen on KDE as well